# Interact between winforms and console application and the observer design pattern

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, console, observer-pattern

i just finished a basic observer pattern in C# console application. Its a basic server client application in which i have used the observer pattern.Now i want to integrate it with a winform application. there is a button on the winform. Every time a message is received by the server, the button must change color or something to that effect. So basically i want the console app to interact with the winform. So now i want to use the observer pattern here. Whenever the server receives the message it notifies the button in the winform and this button which is the observer changes its color or blinks or something to that effect.

Any suggestion would be really helpful

Regards

Comment: How does your `winforms application` start? Is it started/run by some command line in `Console` window?

Comment: @King King its a completely separate process/application

Comment: Is the winform application of yours? I mean you can add code in that application (before building)?

Comment: how can i update the button from the console application...if that is complex then is there any other way?

Comment: yes, you can do with `IPC - Interprocess communication`. However there are many kinds of `IPC`, most of them require to be checked out first by the `firewall`. I've found this one which is very helpful and simple, please wait while I'm adding the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem in fact is to allow your `Console` application to control the `Winforms` application. So to make it simple, I make this demo and it's easy to implement your own way:

Your `Console` application code:

```
 //Must add reference to System.Drawing.dll
 //using namespaces:
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Drawing;
 //..........................
 class Program {
    //This is used to send custom message to your Winforms
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    //This is used to find your winforms window
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);
    //This is used to register custom message so that it's ensured to be unique
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string msgName);
    //Our main method
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int red = RegisterColorCode(Color.Red);
        int yellow = RegisterColorCode(Color.Yellow);
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter color letter: ");
            string r = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            int msg = 0;
            if(r == "r") msg = red;
            if(r == "y") msg = yellow;
            //You can define more colors
            if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)                              
                hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Winforms Application");
            if(hwnd != IntPtr.Zero) SetBackColor(msg);
        }
    }
    IntPtr hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    static int RegisterColorCode(Color c){
        return RegisterWindowMessage(c.ToString());
    }
    static void SetBackColor(int colorCode){
        SendMessage(hwnd, colorCode, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Your `Winforms` application code:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int RegisterWindowMessage(string msgName);
    public Form1(){
        InitializeComponent();
        red = RegisterColorCode(Color.Red);
        yellow = RegisterColorCode(Color.Yellow);
        //Set your form caption to a specified (must be unique at the time it runs)
        Text = "Winforms Application";
    }
    int red,yellow;//you can define more
    private int RegisterColorCode(Color c){
        return RegisterWindowMessage(c.ToString());
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch(m.Msg){
           case red:
              yourButton.BackColor = Color.Red;
              return;
           case yellow:
              yourButton.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
              return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

This is a very simple application model, it uses `Message` to communicate with other windows. However it has some limitation. As you can see, we have to define `certain Color codes` which can be sent from this to that in both sides. I'm trying to send any data from this to that via the `Message.WParam` and `Message.LParam` pointers. However it's not such easy. Different processes have different blocks of memory which are protected.

I use `FindWindow` to find the `winforms window`, which is not always true (there may be some other windows having the same caption). However it's just for demonstrative purpose, it's not complete, it's just a demo. You can search for how to find the exact window (it's not too complicated, just more code to work with).

If you want to send arbitrary data between windows, you can try other `IPC` approaches. If I can improve this answer (so that we can send arbitrary color from `Console` to your `winforms`), I'll update later.

### UPDATE

The solution above works great for simple requirement, it just sends **custom messages** to signal what the sender wants the receiver to do. However to send arbitrary data, you have to send the message `WM_COPYDATA = 0x4a`. There is a struct of `COPYDATASTRUCT` which contains data to be sent and some code to identify what the sender wants the receiver to do. Here is the demo for you:

Console code:

```
 class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, ref COPYDATASTRUCT lParam);
    [DllImport("user32", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        IntPtr hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;     
        while (true)
        {
            //require entering 3 elements of a Color: RED GREEN BLUE (each one is maximum at 255 and minimum at 0
            Console.Write("Enter color R G B: ");//should enter something like 100 200 50
            string[] s = Console.ReadLine().Split(new string[]{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Color colorToBeSent = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(s[0]),int.Parse(s[1]), int.Parse(s[2]));
            COPYDATASTRUCT data = new COPYDATASTRUCT();
            try
            {
                data.dwData = new IntPtr(123456);
                data.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Color));
                data.lpData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.cbSize);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(colorToBeSent, data.lpData, true);
                if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)                              
                    hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Winforms Application");
                if (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    SendMessage(hwnd, 0x4a, IntPtr.Zero, ref data);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(data.lpData);
            }
        }
    }
    public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr dwData;
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr lpData;
    }
```

Winforms code:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
      if(m.Msg == 0x4a)//WM_COPYDATA
      {
         COPYDATASTRUCT data = (COPYDATASTRUCT) m.GetLParam(typeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
            if (data.dwData.ToInt32() == 123456)//Check if this is sent from your Console
            {
                Color c = (Color)Marshal.PtrToStructure(data.lpData, typeof(Color));
                yourButton.BackColor = c;
                return;
            }
      }
      base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    public struct COPYDATASTRUCT
    {
        public IntPtr dwData;
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr lpData;
    } 
}
```

Comment: @kewal in fact, I must say thank you, I've never done this before (although I know about other `IPC`), thanks to your question, I've dug into it :)

Comment: just 2 questions though: what kind of IPC is this ? and,           Do i have to add the form as a reference in the console and vice versa as i get Object reference required in some parameters and not found in this context...Normally when i get these errors i just include the respective file as a reference but if i include now will it still be IPC

Comment: @kewal yes, you have to add some references to your `Console`: `System.Drawing`, `using System.Runtime.InteropServices;` It's still some kind of `IPC` `IPC` stands for `Inter-Process Commmunication`

Comment: yes i did add those same two...using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing; However using System.Drawing does not work..says that does not exist in the System namespace...anyways i will figure it out somehow...once again thanks mate

Comment: well i found it..just had to add reference to the dll...thanks

Comment: I just implemented the code that you gave...and it works like a charm..really interesting way...thanks again

Comment: @kewal that's not all, I think I've found how to send any arbitrary data, (that means we can send any color), in fact this mechanism stands on top of `mapped-file IPC`. I'll update soon :).

Comment: cool... i am also working on something interesting...every time the server console window gets a message then the button color is changed to red..now i am trying that once the message has been read then the button color turns back to the original Control color...i will keep you posted...

Comment: @kewal OK, I updated with the best solution. However I think you may want to keep using the old one, because it looks like it's right for your requirement.